# Selecting a file in Xcode using Applescript

Tags: ios, xcode5, applescript

I would like to open an Xcode project and select the Xcode project (.xcodeproj)in the project navigator using `applescript`.
I tried the following code snippet for `Finder`and Iam able to select the file.

```
tell application "Finder" to select file "README.txt" of folder "Image" of folder "Downloads" of home
```

I would like to do the same in Xcode.I tried the following snippets,but I am not able to select the file in the Xcode project navigator.How to select the file using `applescript` in Xcode

```
tell application "Xcode"
open file "Users:xxxxx:Downloads:Project1:Project1.xcodeproj"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Xcode"
    select file "README.txt" of folder "Project1" of folder "Downloads" of home
    end tell
end tell 

 tell application "Xcode" to select file "README.txt" of folder "Project1" of folder "Downloads" of home
```

Answer (score 0):

Have Xcode open the individual file. You can then update the Navigator pane. Here's code (you may have to adjust file paths and delay intervals):

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate
    -- open project 
    open file "Users:xxxxxx:Downloads:Project1:"
    delay 0.2
    -- open individual file
    open file "Users:xxxxxx:Downloads:Project1:Project1:README.txt"
end tell
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Xcode"
        -- Move focus to next area, the individual file
        keystroke "`" using {command down, option down}
        delay 0.1
        -- Reveal in Project Navigator
        keystroke "j" using {command down, shift down}
    end tell
end tell
```